# Gazebo GUI doesn't show up

Tags: gazebo

I tried Gazebo 9 and 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 MATE and it quits in a few seconds without showing Gazebo GUI. I'm running it on 32-bit Intel CPU with 950 Graphics chipset (pretty old). Here is what I see in the terminal:

```
paul@paul-tc4400:~$ gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.0.6
```

I would appreciate any ideas how to fix or diagnose this issue.

Comment: Run it with ‘—verbose’ and check the log file.

Answer (score 0):

> System requirements
>
> Gazebo is currently best used on Ubuntu, a flavor of Linux. You will
>   need a computer that has:
>
> A dedicated GPU,
>
> Nvidia cards tend to work well in Ubuntu
>
> A CPU that is at least an Intel I5, or equivalent,
>
> At least 500MB of free disk space,
>
> Ubuntu Trusty or later installed.

You have an incompatible CPU with Gazebo's requirements.

Comment: CPU is compatible, it seems that nvidia GPU is required.

Comment: @PaulJurczak nvidia is not a requirement. I’m using different graphics card and it works.